# How to show the category of custom taxonomy

Tags: categories

In the built category, we can use `has_category()` and `the_category()` to show if the post has category and the name of the category.

Now, I am using my custom post type and custom taxonomy. The above two functions are invalid in this case. I wonder what's the API to use here? Thank you.

Comment: The underlying function used by `has_category()` is [`has_term()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_term/), you can use it for any taxonomies including custom ones.

Comment: Thanks! Will try

Answer (score 1):

Usually I used `has_term()` and `the_terms()`.

These are the examples

```
if( has_term('', 'genre') ){
    // do something
}
```

```
the_terms( $post->ID, 'category', 'categories: ', ' / ' );
```

OR, I used this to get a list `get_the_term_list()`

for example

```
echo get_the_term_list($post->ID, 'category', '', ', ');
```

Comment: Thank you, will try this.

Answer (score 0):

I found this working method, in case you are interested.

```
if ( true === $show_categories && has_category() ) {
            ?>

            <div class="entry-categories">
                <span class="screen-reader-text"><?php _e( 'Categories', 'twentytwenty' ); ?></span>
                <div class="entry-categories-inner">
                    <?php the_category( ' ' ); ?>
                </div><!-- .entry-categories-inner -->
            </div><!-- .entry-categories -->

            <?php
            
        // custom post type
        } else {
            $post_type = get_post_type();  
            $category =  $post_type . '_cat';
            $taxonomy_names = wp_get_object_terms(get_the_ID(), $category);
            
            if (true === $show_categories && !empty($taxonomy_names) ) {
                $term = array_pop($taxonomy_names);
                ?>
                <div>
                    <span><?php _e( 'Categories:', 'twentytwenty' ); ?></span>
                    <a href="<?php echo get_term_link( $term->slug, $category ); ?> "> <?php echo $term->name; ?> </a>
                </div><!-- .entry-categories -->
                <?php
            }
            
        }
```

And this is the [example link](https://www.jobyme88.com/?st_ai=get_object_taxonomies), if you want to see the result.